# Edit plugin config in UnitTest Shopware

Tags: php, shopware

I would like to test the function of a plugin that uses a plugin config.

is it possible to edit the config of a plugin in a UnitTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good idea to look for existing tests as an example.

For example full-text-search for "Config" in
`vendor/shopware/storefront/Test`.

This leads
to `vendor/shopware/storefront/Test/Page/ProductPageTest.php:93` for example:

```
// enable hideCloseoutProductsWhenOutOfStock filter
$this->getContainer()->get(SystemConfigService::class)
     ->set('core.listing.hideCloseoutProductsWhenOutOfStock', true);
```